# Alfa Awus036ach causes password prompt loop, won't connect

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, networkmanager

I want to use my Alfa Awus 036ach wireless card in my Debian 9 (stretch) system. 
The system is dual boot; the other OS Kali Linux, where the cards works properly, so I assume this is not a hardware issue.

As in Debian repos there is no realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms packet, I downloaded and properly installed all the following drivers from Github:

https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU.git
https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.9.git
https://github.com/astsam/rtl8812au.git
https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au.git

All of them give the same outcome: NetworkManager properly recognizes the card after loading the kernel module, but when I try to connect to my network it loops prompting the password request, even if the password is correct.

These are the (in my opinion) relevant lines of `journalctl -u NetworkManager`:

```
may 15 02:17:34 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info> 
[1557879454.6139] manager: (cscotun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)may 15 02:17:34 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879454.6227] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/cscotun0, iface: cscotun0)
may 15 02:17:34 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879454.6227] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/cscotun0, iface: cscotun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
may 15 02:17:34 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879454.6250] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/cscotun0, iface: cscotun0)
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.4568] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): Activation: starting connection 'vodafoneECCB 1' (dd67b02d-b321-4a7e-88af-b8c8924bc124)
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.4571] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="dd67b02d-b321-4a7e-88af-b8c8924bc124" name="vodafoneECCB 1" pid=1210 uid=1000 result="success"
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.4572] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.4848] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 00:C0:CA:95:BB:74 (preserve)
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.4867] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.4869] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): Activation: (wifi) access point 'vodafoneECCB 1' has security, but secrets are required.
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.4869] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5551] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5559] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5565] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): Activation: (wifi) connection 'vodafoneECCB 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5565] Config: added 'ssid' value 'vodafoneECCB'
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5565] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5565] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5565] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5565] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
may 15 02:18:14 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879494.5731] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
may 15 02:18:18 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879498.9451] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
may 15 02:18:24 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <warn>  [1557879504.9288] sup-iface[0x561c416ca040,wlx00c0ca95bb74]: connection disconnected (reason 15)
may 15 02:18:24 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879504.9337] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
may 15 02:18:24 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879504.9346] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
may 15 02:18:24 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879504.9347] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect') [50 60 8]
may 15 02:18:25 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879505.0337] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.1956] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8627] keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vodafoneECCB 1 (dd67b02d-b321-4a7e-88af-b8c8924bc124,"vodafoneECCB 1")
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8696] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8704] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8706] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): Activation: (wifi) connection 'vodafoneECCB 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8706] Config: added 'ssid' value 'vodafoneECCB'
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8707] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8707] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8707] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8707] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
may 15 02:18:29 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879509.8901] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
may 15 02:18:30 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879510.1060] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
may 15 02:18:36 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <warn>  [1557879516.0892] sup-iface[0x561c416ca040,wlx00c0ca95bb74]: connection disconnected (reason 15)
may 15 02:18:36 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879516.0933] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
may 15 02:18:36 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879516.0943] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
may 15 02:18:36 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879516.0944] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect') [50 60 8]
may 15 02:18:36 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879516.1933] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
may 15 02:18:38 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <warn>  [1557879518.8341] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): User canceled the secrets request.
may 15 02:18:38 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879518.8342] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
may 15 02:18:38 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <warn>  [1557879518.8348] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): Activation: failed for connection 'vodafoneECCB 1'
may 15 02:18:38 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879518.8354] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
may 15 02:18:38 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879518.8397] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to EA:58:F3:EC:3D:55 (scanning)
may 15 02:18:38 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879518.8428] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
may 15 02:18:42 huitzilopotli NetworkManager[627]: <info>  [1557879522.9968] device (wlx00c0ca95bb74): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
may 15 02:17:26 huitzilopotli dhclient[779]: bound to 192.168.1.37 -- renewal in 17589 seconds.
```

If I try to connect without NetworkManager (i. e. via terminal) it connects properly to internet. So I assume this is a NetworkManager problem.

I don't need the card to inject, just want to use it to have better internet connection.